# Ler uma arquivo txt pelo php e mysql e visualizado por cada usuário

Tags: php, matemática

Sou programador iniciante em PHP, aceitei um desafio de um trabalho e neste momento estou necessitando de uma ajuda. Eles me enviam todo o mês um relatório de gastos de cada usuário em um único arquivo (uma lista), no formato txt. Preciso converter as linhas separadamente de cada usuário, para que ele possa visualizar seus gastos somados em um total. Gostaria de algum comando em PHP, vinculado com um banco MySQL, para que ele possa visualizar os seus gastos.

**Obs.:** O arquivo recebido em txt, é uma lista com todos os usuários. Abaixo uma parte do arquivo recebido para que possam entender.

> 000001|06|2015|001|MENSALIDADE JUNHO DE 2015                                                 |000000003000|D
>   000001|06|2015|002|CLUBE CRUZEIRO DO SUL                                                           |000000004500|D
>   000005|06|2015|001|DEVOLUCAO DE CREDITO PARA SOCIO                                                 |000000007500|C

Separados pelo pipe estão primeiramente o id do usuário, mês e depois o ano, a ordem, a entidade e (tirando os zeros) o valor gasto em cada entidade.

Comment: O problema é inserir no banco? Edite a pergunta e formate as linhas do txt exatamente como estão no seu arquivo, selecione o código e use o botão `{ }` para formatar.

Comment: Não estou sabendo fazer, como separar cada coluna com respectiva característica pelo banco, para ser visualizado pelo usuário. Ex.: 000001(usuário), 06/2015 (data), 001 MENSALID...(entidade) e somar os valores de cada linha do usuário 30,00 + 45,00 Total: 75,00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está uma forma de fazer isso:

```
function readMyFile($file) {
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    $collection = explode("\n",$data);
    $collection = array_filter($collection);

    $keys = array(
                 'id_usuario',
                 'mes',
                 'ano',
                 'ordem',
                 'entidade',
                 'valor_gasto',
                 'categoria'
                 );
    $return = array();
    if (count($collection)) {
       foreach ($collection as $linha => $collection_pipes) {

       $resultLine = explode('|',$collection_pipes);

      $resultMap[$linha] = array_map(function($a, $b) {
                                        if ($a == 'valor_gasto') {
                                             //remove os zeros
                                            $b = (int) $b; 
                                        }
                                     return array($a => trim($b));
                                    },$keys, $resultLine);
          /* se for remover o índice 0,
             coloque o trecho do código abaixo aqui */
      }
   }

return $resultMap;
}

$saida = readMyFile('seuarquivo.txt');

//sua saída
   echo '<pre>';
    print_r($saida);
```

Considerando que seu arquivo quebre linhas, a saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_usuario] => 000001
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [mes] => 06
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ano] => 2015
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ordem] => 001
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [entidade] => MENSALIDADE JUNHO DE 2015
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [valor_gasto] => 3000
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [categoria] => D
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_usuario] => 000001
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [mes] => 06
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ano] => 2015
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ordem] => 002
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [entidade] => CLUBE CRUZEIRO DO SUL
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [valor_gasto] => 4500
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [categoria] => D
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_usuario] => 000005
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [mes] => 06
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ano] => 2015
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ordem] => 001
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [entidade] => DEVOLUCAO DE CREDITO PARA SOCIO
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [valor_gasto] => 7500
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [categoria] => C
                )

        )

)
```

Para remover o índice numérico duplicado, é só colocar esse trecho do código dentro do **foreach**:

```
   $resultMap[$linha] =  array('id_usuario'=>$resultMap[$linha][0]['id_usuario'],
                                'mes'=>$resultMap[$linha][1]['mes'],
                                'ano'=>$resultMap[$linha][2]['ano'],
                                'ordem'=>$resultMap[$linha][3]['ordem'],
                                'entidade'=>$resultMap[$linha][4]['entidade'],
                                'valor_gasto'=>$resultMap[$linha][5]['valor_gasto'],
                                'categoria'=>$resultMap[$linha][6]['categoria']);
```

Ou se preferir, coloque isso depois do foreach:

```
$resultMap =  array_map(function($arr) {
                 return array_merge($arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3],$arr[4],$arr[5],$arr[6]);
}, $resultMap);
return $resultMap;
```

A outra forma de fazer é essa:

```
function readMyFile($file) {

$content = fopen($file, "r");
if ($content) {
    $total = 0;
   $collection = array();
    while (($line = fgets($content)) !== false) {

        $data = explode("|",$line);
        $collection[$total] = array(
                 'id_usuario' => $data[0],
                 'mes'        => $data[1],
                 'ano'        => $data[2],
                 'ordem'      => $data[3],
                 'entidade'   => $data[4],
                 'valor_gasto'=>(int) $data[5],
                 'categoria'  => $data[6]
                 );

        $total++;       
    }
     return $collection;
    fclose($content);
} 
$collection = readMyFile('seuarquivo.txt');
 echo '<pre>';
  print_r($collection);
```

Comment: Não entendi o porque do `array_filter()` na quarta linha.

Comment: Obrigado Ivan, pela ajuda. Vou fazer alguns testes com meu banco de dados para que cada usuário possa visualizar individualmente.

Comment: o `array_filter()` é para remover os valores nulos das linhas "\n"

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um script simples para pegar os dados do arquivo texto no formato que você enviou, segue:

```
<?php 

$handle = fopen("dados.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $total = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $data = explode("|",$line);

        echo "ID: ".$data[0]."</br>";
        echo "Mês: ".$data[1]."</br>";
        echo "Ano: ".$data[2]."</br>";
        echo "Ordem: ".$data[3]."</br>";
        echo "Entidade: ".$data[4]."</br>";
        echo "Valor: R$".number_format($data[5],2)."</br>";
        echo "Cod: ".$data[6]."</br>";
        $total+=$data[5];       
    }

    echo '</br>Total: R$' . number_format($total, 2);

    fclose($handle);
} else {
} 

?>
```

Só para você ter uma ideia, mas você pode salvar no banco de dados também.

Comment: Obrigado Henrique, pela ajuda. Vou fazer alguns ajustes com banco de dados, para que cada usuário possa visualizar o seus gastos individualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Pode gravar cada coluna no banco de dados fazem um `explode()` pelo pipe, caso não sejam muitas linhas pode usar `file()` para abrir o arquivo como um array.

```
<?php

$linhas = file('gastos');//abre o arquivo como um array 
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7) values ";

//define o padrão do insert
$pls = '('. str_repeat('?,', 7) .'),';
$sql .= trim(str_repeat($pls, count($linhas)), ',');

//monta o array com os valores a serem inseridos
$valores = array();
foreach($linhas as $item){
    $valores = array_merge($valores, explode('|', $item));
}



$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'usuario', 'senha');
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt->execute($valores)){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Obrigado rray, pela ajuda. Vou fazer alguns ajustes com o meu banco de dados, para que cada usuário possa visualizar o seus gastos individualmente.